# How compare int with int model json and mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I try to compare a int variable received by parameter with int field in DB.

Function in Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult getServicoID(string serie, int numDoc)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = db.Servicos.Where(dados => dados.DadosComerciais.Serie == serie && dados.DadosComerciais.NumDoc == numDoc); // i think the problem is here - dados.DadosComerciais.NumDoc == numDoc
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Function js:

```
function AddServContratado() {
//Buscar ServicoID da tabela servicos para guardar na ServicoContratado

$.getJSON("/Contrato/getServicoID", { serie: $("#Serie").val(), numDoc: $("#NumDoc").val() },
      function (result) {
          var servicoID = result.ServicosID;
          alert(result.ServicosID);
      });
```

Comment: what is context of error ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution:

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult getServicoID(string serie, int numDoc)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = db.Servicos.FirstOrDefault(dados => dados.DadosComerciais.Serie == serie && dados.DadosComerciais.NumDoc == numDoc);

            return Json(result.ServicosID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Js:

```
    $.getJSON("/Contrato/getServicoID", { serie: $("#Serie").val(), numDoc: $("#NumDoc").val() },
      function (result) {
          var servicoID = result;
          alert(result);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a list from your controller action. The `result` variable is an `IEnumerable<Servico>`.

And in your javascript file you are attempting to use some `result.ServicosID` property which cannot work because you have a list of objects. You could access them for example like this: `result[0].ServicosID`.

If you want to access a single object then make sure you have returned a single object from your controller action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetServicoID(string serie, int numDoc)
{
    try
    {
        var result = db.Servicos.FirstOrDefault(dados => dados.DadosComerciais.Serie == serie && dados.DadosComerciais.NumDoc == numDoc);
        if (result == null)
        {
            // no object found in the database that matches the criteria => 404
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: i try do return a single object. this fields are primary keys in DadosComerciais and foreign keys in Servicos, will only return single object result

Comment: Either do as Darin is suggesting, or simply add .FirstOrDefault() to your linq. Where() will return a list wether you have a single result or not.

Comment: @CésarCação, did you notice the `FirstOrDefault` in my answer?